# How to made extent report working in offline mode

Tags: selenium, report, extent

We have alreadly implemneted extent reeport in our project and it is working perfectly when Internet is ON.
My problem is I want to run my script on server where no internet is available ,only application are running .
Can I get guide here to make my reporting working in offline mode.
Many Thanks in advance

Comment: This feature is only available with the professional version.  See here http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/3/java/#offline-report

Comment: Thank you Anshoo..My problem has been solved now :)